# Word Mail Merge Template Set-Up

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-word-2013, mail-merge

I know how to perform a mail merge from within word, but my question is, how can I create a mail merge template that I can open from an external source such as Excel and automatically map the headers in Excel to the merge fields in Word?

I started with this tutorial, https://www.textcontrol.com/blog/2011/02/04/creating-mail-merge-templates-in-ms-word-2010/ but it does not sthow how to save it as a mail merge template.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the Mail Merge from Excel, using the Excel Sheet as Database, you need to perform the following task.

**Part One:**

In Excel enter Mailing data with appropriate Headings.

Like First Name, Last Name, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip Code. Since these headings will be used as Field Name in Word while Mail Merge.

**NB:** If you don't want to use Excel data source, you can use a contact list or an address book in a TXT or CSV file. For this Text Import Wizard help you to get data as TXT or CSV file into Excel.

**Part Two:**

This part is not very difficult. You need to perform usual Mail Merge procedure.
Like start with Blank File, Go to Mailing TAB, find Select Recipients.

Hit existing list, find Excel file, if required edit the Recipient's list.

Next is insert fields to Merge and arrange them.

*Finally Preview and finish the Mail Merge and save this File as Template.*

**Another Method should be the Reverse of the above procedure.**

Like, start from Word and while connecting to the Mailing Data you may have many choices. You may go with Excel, Access or other Data sources including DDE(Dynamic Data Exchange) method.

*Hope this help You.*